# Load Image to the corner of ImageView

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I need to load an image of specific size in the corner of Imageview

[image]

I don't want to add several Imageviews because i don't want to lose my collapsing toolbar animations

UPDATE: Added xml part

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


     <net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="@color/darkGray"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBarTopic"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="5dp"

                >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    />
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    />
            </net.opacapp.multilinecollapsingtoolbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Put up your code trials

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Relative layout inside the Coordinator Layout.